# Npm workspaces - call workspace script from root package

Tags: node.js, npm, workspace, monorepo

I'm struggling with multiple npm packages in a root git repository with custom dev scripts to handle launch, compile, build and so on. Now I came across npm workspaces and wanted to use this stunning new feature in my following project structure but I can't get it to work:

```
projectx (root)
- package.json
- apps   
 -- backend
   -- src
   -- package.json (name: @projectx/backend, scripts: "dev":"ts-node or whatever")
 -- common
   -- src
   -- package.json (name: @projectx/common)
 -- frontend
   -- src
   -- package.json (name: @projectx/frontend, scripts: "dev":"webpack")
```

My root package.json contains:

```
    {
  "name": "packagex",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": "true",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "back:dev": "npm workspace @projectx/backend dev",
    "front:dev": "npm workspace @projectx/frontend dev",
    "dev": "run-p back:dev front:dev"
  },
  "workspaces": [
    "apps/*"
  ],
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git_url"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

And now I want to start backend and frontend with npm-run-all and the command on root: npm run dev which results in:

[image: Screenshot of terminal output]

And I also want to share the common package with backend and frontend, which should be possible in this case. Maybe anobody else is facing the same problem or has some ideas what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `"workspaces"` property in package.json looks right. I'm using NPM Workspaces and it's working well, but it's still missing a lot of features so you need to wire things up yourself. I also don't think `npm worksace` is a command (but maybe for the future?), so here's a checklist to get it to work:

- Make sure you're using Node 15+ and NPM 7+
- Set all package.json to `"private": true,`
- Delete all `package-lock.json` inside of your project, go to the root, then `npm install`. It should generate one root level `package-lock.json` that contains all dependencies for your workspaces
- Since you're using `npm-run-all`, add this to your scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "back:dev": "cd apps/backend && npm run dev",
    "front:dev": "cd apps/fontend && npm run dev",
    "dev": "npm-run-all build --parallel back:dev front:dev"
  }
```

Then start it with `npm run dev`.

Note, you may want to consider using `start` scripts instead of `dev` to shorten the command you need to type (e.g. `npm start` instead of `npm run dev`), but `npm run dev` will still be fine.

Comment: I can't see any notice requirement for node15/16.  Today LTS is still limited to node14, isn't it?

Comment: @CraigHicks NPM 7+ is required for workspaces support. Node 15+ come with NPM 7+. You can use an older version of Node, but then you'll need to explicitly upgrade NPM to 7+.

Comment: Correct.  I'm using NPM 7 with Node 14, because Node 16 (not yet LTS) was causing some errors.  Didn't try Node 15.

Answer (score 25):

npm@7.7.0 added a way to call scripts from child packages/workspaces, here are some examples based on your original:

**Running a script named "dev" in all workspaces located under `apps/backend`:**

`npm run dev -w apps/backend`

**Running a script named "dev" in all workspaces:**

`npm run dev --ws`

**Running a script named "dev" in a package named `@projectx/frontend`:**

`npm run dev -w @projectx/frontend`

**More info:**

- Related CHANGELOG entry: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v7.7.0
- Docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-run-script#workspaces-support
- Blog post: https://dev.to/ruyadorno/npm-workspaces-npm-run-and-exec-1lg0

Comment: A problem that I faced which is not obvious from docs or your (great) summary of the feature: **workspaces are not named after the folders, _even though_ you configure them pointing to folders; they're named after the `package.json:name` inside each of the workspaces**. Thus, given the OP's example, I was trying to `npm run dev -w frontend` instead of `npm run dev -w @projectx/frontend`, or `npm run dev -w apps/frontend`.

Answer (score 6):

In root `package.json` you can also add short name for each package:

```
  "scripts": {
    "api": "npm --workspace=@app/api run",
  }
```

`@app/api` is a name in `package.json`

And run scripts in `./packages/api` folder from root like so:

```
npm run api lint
npm run api dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wish to:

- keep scripts and dependencies separate (thus the 4 `package.json` files), for ease of maintenance

May I suggest a work-around without workspaces that might do what you're after:

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "//back:dev": "npm workspace @projectx/backend dev",
    "back:dev": "npm --prefix apps/backend dev",

    "//front:dev": "npm workspace @projectx/frontend dev",
    "front:dev": "npm --prefix apps/frontend dev",

    "dev": "run-p back:dev front:dev"
  },
  "//workspaces": [
    "apps/*"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@local/back": "file:apps/backend",
    "@local/front": "file:apps/frontend",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5"
  }
}
```

The `npm --prefix` runs npm scripts in another folder than the current one.

The `@local/back` dependencies are not necessary for that, but I've found such useful if eg. a package depends on another. You might use that trick to reach for the common by:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@local/common": "file:../common"
  }
```

I wished a week ago that workspaces would offer a better solution, but didn't find any benefit over the above mechanisms.

I would *also* like workspaces to:

- only expose those files in the `files` entry of the particular `package.json` (now, all are shown)
- only allow `import` to paths in the `exports` of the particular `package.json`, if it has one

See
[NPM Workspaces monorepo - share local package's distribution folder as root instead of the entire source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66785791/npm-workspaces-monorepo-share-local-packages-distribution-folder-as-root-inst)

Answer (score 0):

This approach leverages the `--prefix` flag to specify the folder for running development scripts and utilizes the concurrently package to execute multiple NPM scripts simultaneously. The `-n` flag assigns names to each task for clarity, while the `-c` flag adds color to differentiate between them visually.

1. use `--prefix <folderName>`
2. use concurrently

I am not familiar with the package that is used by the original question but this is an alternative

```
 "scripts": {
    "back:dev": "npm run dev --prefix client",  // runs dev in ./cleint/packaga.json
    "front:dev": "npm run dev --prefix front",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run back:dev"\" \"npm run front:dev\""
  }
```

[image: concurrently output]

`[0]` is the first command and `[1]` is the second command

We can replace this with `--name` or `-n` flag

```
"dev": "concurrently -n \"BE,FE\" \"npm run back:dev"\" \"npm run front:dev\""
```

[image: concurrently --name output]

we can even add colors with `--color` and `-c` flag

```
"dev": "concurrently -n \"BE,FE\" -c \"green,blue\" \"npm run back:dev"\" \"npm run front:dev\""
```

[image]