# NPM Workspaces monorepo - share local package's distribution folder as root instead of the entire source files

Tags: npm, monorepo, npm-workspaces

Using NPM Workspaces, I'm sharing one package (`components`) with others (`webapp1` and `webapp2`). Something like this:

```
root
  apps   
    webapp1
    webapp2
  packages
    components
```

Everything is working well, but everything inside `components`, include source code in the `src` folder is being shared. Since `components`' compiled output folder is `dist`, I'd like to only share that folder. This is how it looks in the root `node_modules`:

[image]

The problem is that when I need to import in `webapp1` or `webapp2`, my import path has to include the `dist` folder. Here's the intellisense that I get from VS Code:

[image]

And this is how I import in `webapp1` and `webapp2`:

```
import Center from '@mycompany/components/dist/Center'
```

While everything works, how can I set up my NPM Workspaces so that only the contents of the `dist` folder is shared in its root?

I've tried NPM's [files](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#files) and `.npmignore` inside the `components` folder to ignore everything except for the `dist` folder, but that doesn't seem to work. The `main` property in package.json for `components` is also set to point to `dist/index.js`:

```
"main": "dist/index.js"
```

Interestingly, if I want to import `dist/index.js` file, I can do it without `dist`:

```
import foo from '@mycompany/components'
```

...however, importing anything other than `dist/index.js` requires `dist` to be included in the path.

Comment: Very interested to see what answers you get! I tried workspaces today (npm 7.7.5) and was disappointed to realise they don't seem to offer access restrictions.

Comment: @akauppi Can you elaborate on what you mean by access restriction? NPM Workspaces is very new and missing a lot of features, but with a bunch of manually created npm scripts inside package.json, I've made it work well for my workflow.

Comment: I probably meant encapsulation. That a sub package would be seen only by its `files` exposed, not everything in the source directory. Now (npm 7.7.5), it looks like a symbolic link to all of the sub package contents. Before, I was using `file:` links and continue doing that since I wasn't able to figure out the benefit workspaces provide.

Comment: I think you wrote it better than me: "but everything inside components, include source code in the src folder is being shared. Since components' compiled output folder is dist, I'd like to only share that folder." Same thing I'd like to see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should treat the packages folder as a collection of dist folders in your use case.

In this scenario, you would move your `packages/components/src` folder somewhere else in your project and then build to `packages/components` instead of `packages/components/dist`

```
root
  apps   
    webapp1
    webapp2
  packages
    components
  src
    components
```

I have a similar setup in this [tooling monorepo](https://github.com/nickstaroba/eterna-tooling) I created

Comment: Interesting, can you share what `components`' package.json would look like to point to build folder? Would `main` in package.json be something like `.../../packages/components/index.js`?

Comment: `packages/components/package.json` should be the same as the original `src/components/dist/package.json`. Whatever those settings were... In a library I built which outputs CommonJS and ES Modules, the relevant entries in package.json were:
`"main": "index.js"` and 
`"module": "index.esm.js"`

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to @nicksaroba's approach, if you don't want to restructure your project layout, you can just setup an alias:

```js
// apps/webapp/webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    // ...
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "components": "@mycompany/components/dist/"
        }
    },
    // ...
};
```